# UseEffect hook doesn't rerender the component when I update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a component in which I am getting users from the database and then checking which users are not admin and displaying them in a list so that they can be approved or rejected. I am using redux toolkit as a state management library. As you can see in the code I am dispatching an action called `getAllUsers()` in the `useEffect` hook. The `getAllUsers()` actions fetches all the users from the database and returns and array which I destructure from users using `useSelector` hook.

If I pass users in the dependency array of useEffect I get infinite loop which is of course expected behaviour because the reference of the array changes.

In my user array which I get from `getAllUsers` action, I have user objects which contains multiple attributes like name, email etc. among those attributes I have an attribute called `isAdmin`. As you can see I am dispatching an action called `approveUser`, it simply just marks that `isAdmin` value to `true`.

How can I make it such that as I approve the user gets approved and hence gets removed from the component.

Approve User Component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getAllUsers, approveUser } from "../../features/users/userSlice";
import { useStyles } from "../../hooks/useStyles";
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cancel';
import {
TableContainer,
Table,
TableHead,
TableBody,
TableRow,
TableCell,
Paper,
CircularProgress,
Button,
Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

const Approval = () => {
const { users, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { loaderContainer } = useStyles()

useEffect(() => {
dispatch(getAllUsers());
console.log(users)
}, [])

return (
  <TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table aria-label="simple table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell><Typography variant="subtitle1">Name</Typography></TableCell>
          <TableCell><Typography variant="subtitle1">Email</Typography></TableCell>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          { users && users.data.map((user) => {
              if (!user.isAdmin) {
                return (
                  <TableRow key={user.name} sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th':{border: 0} }}>
                      <TableCell><Typography variant="subtitle1">{user.name}</Typography></TableCell>
                      <TableCell><Typography variant="subtitle1">{user.email}</Typography></TableCell>
                      <TableCell><Button endIcon={<CheckCircleIcon />} style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF7B00', color: 'white' }} onClick={() => {
                        dispatch(approveUser({ _id: user._id, isAdmin: true, isSuperUser: false }))
                      }} variant="contained">Approve</Button></TableCell>
                      <TableCell><Button endIcon={<CancelIcon />} style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF7B00', color: 'white' }} onClick={() => {
                        
                      }} variant="contained">Reject</Button></TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              }
            })}
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
);   
};

export default Approval;
```

User Slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const users = 'http://localhost:5000/api/users';
const loginUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/login';
const signupUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/signup';
const approve = 'http://localhost:5000/api/approve';

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('user/loginUser', async 
(data) => {
const response = await axios.post(loginUrl, data);
return response;
})

export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk('user/signupUser', async 
(data) => {
const response = await axios.post(signupUrl, data);
return response;
})

export const getAllUsers = createAsyncThunk('user/getAllUsers', 
async () => {
const response = await axios.get(users);
return response;
})

export const approveUser = createAsyncThunk('user/approveUser', 
async (data) => {
// console.log(data)
const response = await axios.put(approve, data);
console.log(response)
return response;
})

const initialState = {
user: {},
users: [],
isLoggedIn: false,
isLoading: true
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
name: 'user',
initialState,
reducers: {
    logOutUser: (state) => {
        state.isLoggedIn = false;
        state.user = {};
        state.isLoading = false;
    },
    getPassword: (state, action) => {
        const password = action.payload
        console.log(password)
    }
},
extraReducers: {
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.user = action.payload.data
        state.isLoggedIn = action.payload.data.isLoggedIn
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
    [signupUser.pending]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
    [signupUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.user = action.payload.data
    },
    [signupUser.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
    [getAllUsers.pending]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
    [getAllUsers.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.users = action.payload.data
    },
    [getAllUsers.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
    [approveUser.pending]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
    [approveUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        // state.users = action.payload.data
    },
    [approveUser.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
    },
}
})

export const { getPassword, logOutUser } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

[image]

Comment: You aren't showing what `approveUser` does, so it's hard to help.

Comment: What state are you changing that would cause the component to rerender? I would assume that you would have an `approved` flag in the user data model? Wouldn't you want to conditionally render the "approve" and "disapprove" buttons based on that?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] (please note the "minimal", but also the "reproducible") demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). That would include your Redux code (`approveUser`) and similar.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated the question. Hope this information is ok

Comment: @HaiderMansoor - A proper MRE would be better. But even if not, could you at least indent the code? Asking people for help and then giving them very hard-to-read code isn't a good look. :-)

Comment: I don't see anything in `approveUser` that would trigger an update to the component. All it does is send a message to the server.

Comment: What is `response.data` in `user/approveUser`?

Comment: what is the response of approveUser api call??

Comment: Guys, the approve user action returns the user whose isAdmin is changed to true. by Default isAdmin property is set to false. I do not store it in the state because it should change it in the database and then the getAllUsers should update because in the users array the value of isAdmin in one of the users will be set to true so the array has changed

Comment: Hey Guys, I solved it by returning the updated user array from my backend rather than return just the user object. It fixed my problem. thank you for you answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTK's `createReducer` and `createSlice` use [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) internally to let you write simpler immutable update logic using "mutating" syntax.

Take a look at [Immer update patterns](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns/) under `// update by id`.

You can get the `id` of the approved user from `action.meta.arg._id`. With the id, you can find the index in `state.users`.

Then you can update the `isAdmin` property of that user with  `state.users[id].isAdmin = true`

```
    [approveUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      const id = action.meta.arg._id;
      const foundId = state.users.findIndex((user) => user._id === id);
      if (foundId !== -1) state.users[foundId].isAdmin = true;
    },
```

This is an optimistic update because we can assume to update the user in state.users without needing to dispatch `getAllUsers` again.

[image: Edit react rtk react toolkit r&m api (forked)]